# PageReference loads wrong page on action methods in VF pages embedded in Standard Layout

Tags: visualforce, lightning, embedded

I have a Visualforce page that is used inside the Standard Layout. It contains an `apex:commandLink`

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!activate}" value="Activate" />
```

which will call an Apex method returning a PageReference to another page.

```
public PageReference activate() {
    ...
    return new PageReference('/' + id);
}
```

This worked fine in Aloha but in Lightning Experience it just leads to an empty page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it on my own by replacing the `apex:commandLink` with an `apex:outputlink`

```
<apex:actionFunction name="activate" action="{!activate}" />
<apex:outputlink value="{!url}" onClick="activate();return false;">Activate Next</apex:outputlink>
```

calling

```
public String getUrl() {
    return new PageReference('/' + id).getUrl();
} 

public void activate() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Any insight into why?

Comment: Sorry...but no :(